# Set custom css for wrapping div

Tags: javascript, css, flatpickr

I use timepicker from [flatpickr](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/) and I need to set custom width (for mobile support).
I didn't find function for this. Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
(I needed to set the width not to all of the pickers, but only to certain)

```js
$(".hasTime.noCalendar").wrap('<div class="bells-timepicker"></div>');
```

```css
.bells-timepicker .noCalendar{
    width: 150px;
}
```